# Does D pass value by copy?

Tags: d, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

if I do:

```
myclass a = new myclass();
myclass b = a;
```

Does `b` points to or is a copy of `a`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classes in D use reference semantics so `b` points to the same object as `a`. structs, on the other hand, use value semantics so...

```
auto a = mystruct();
auto b = a;
```

...would refer to distinct objects.